# Как сделать переключение языков на странице?

Tags: javascript, реализация

Есть небольшой лендинг, на котором довольно мало текста, на этом лендинге должен быть переключатель языков `EN / RU`.  Была мысля подгружать переводы текстов из `.json` и через  `js` заменять значения блоков с текстом на другой язык, но мне это **кажется** не самым оптимальным решением для такой задачи.Буду рад если вы предложите мне альтернативу или оставите этот вариант и подскажите как его можно сделать правильнее (наример, там, библиотеку какую нибудь или сделать на ванильном js). 
*P.S. Необязательно именно переключение языков, пойдет и перезагрузка страницы*
*P.S.S. Но желательно конечно все таки переключение поскольку текста мало*

Comment: сделайте 2 разных домена, ru/com, определяете язык браузера и выдаете соот. контент, к примеру: www.example.com/ru/ | www.example.com/en/

Comment: @meine в таком случае нужно сделать одинаковые страницы которые отличаются лишь тем что текст на разных языках?

Comment: почему вы хотите сделать это на фронтенде, а не бэкенде?

Comment: у вас бекенд есть? через бек это делается

Comment: @teran не, бэк тоже норм

Comment: [Нашел возможный аналог вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228835/best-practice-javascript-and-multilanguage)

Comment: простым путем, если текста мало. заведите массив со строками а-ля `['ru' => ['welcome' => "Привет", ....], 'en' => ['welcome' => "Hello"....]]` значение выбранного языка берите из куки. Более сложным путем можно заюзать файлы локализации и gettext.